# How to access data from other homepage with a simple function (no Ajax, no jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I want to access the data returned by this link with a simple function: https://geoapi123.appspot.com/

If you click the link, the return looks like:

```
function geoip_country_code(){return"UK"}
function geoip_country_name(){return"United Kingdom"}
function geoip_city(){return"London"}
...
```

In particular, I'm looking for the geoip_city. I do not want to use AJAX or jQuery.
I need a simple function, which does nor require script tags or any references in the head. The data received needs to be stored in a variable, totally independent from the homepage or any events at the homepage. The function cannot be called by any onload or click events, or anything else happening with the homepage.

Here is a working example with head script tag (**not what I want**):

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://geoapi123.appspot.com/"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
var city = geoip_city();
alert(city);
</script>
</body>
```

Here is an **idea** of what I want:

```
function getLocation() {
    ???                            //access homepage somehow here
    var city = geoip_city();       //get result
    alert(city);                   //alert result
};
getLocation();                     //call function
```

Here is my **closest try so far** (not working, the return is "0"):

```
function accessLocation() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
           alert(xmlhttp.status);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://geoapi123.appspot.com", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
accessLocation();
```

Comment: Most likely not possible without ajax. Can you explain your limitations? Why no ajax/head?

Comment: The reason is, I need to copy & paste the javascript function into the "smart search bar" of my osx safari browser. As it turns out, that smart search bar is not that smart: I cannot use any tag elements or reference to a file, hence I cannot use jQuery/Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a script element by code and loading the source from 'geoapi':

```js
    function clickHandler() {
      var city = geoip_city();
      alert(city);
    }

    function ready() {

      var element = document.getElementById('cityFinder');
      element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
    }

    function init() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.onload = function() {
        ready();
      };
      script.src = "https://geoapi123.appspot.com/";
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```

```html
<body onload="init();">

  

  <input type="button" id="cityFinder" value="Where am I?"></input>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Jorge, that code works, and does what I was asking for! But it's still not what I need. I will edit my original question. What I need is the return stored in a variable, totally independent from any part of the actual homepage. There is not even an "onload" event on the homepage. Let's just assume, there is no homepage at all.